# How to change the locale in WINE for all programs?

Tags: wine, locale, japanese

http://timcampyy.tumblr.com/post/90771619172/emofuri-problem-solved ,

This is what I am trying to solve; it involves me changing the locale to japanese, THEN reinstalling, which is why I need it to affect WINE itself. Any suggestions?